# Expo splashScreen not changing

Tags: android, expo, react-native

So I'm building an app apk file with expo, and I'm pointing to my splashscreen images on app.json.

```
    {
  "expo": {
    "name": "D&D Monster Reference",
    "slug": "dnd-monster-reference",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "mdpi": "./assets/splashScreen/splash-port-mdpi.png",
      "ldpi": "./assets/splashScreen/splash-port-ldpi.png",
      "hdpi": "./assets/splashScreen/splash-port-hdpi.png",
      "xhdpi": "./assets/splashScreen/splash-port-xhdpi.png",
      "xxhdpi": "./assets/splashScreen/splash-port-xxhdpi.png",
      "xxxhdpi": "./assets/splashScreen/splash-port-xxxhdpi.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.example.example",
      "versionCode": 1
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

But when I install the app, I get this default image as my splashcreen.[image]

Am I doing something wrong here? I haven't found anything about it on expo docs.

Answer (score 5):

I have had this issue too on managed workflow. How I solve it is to rename the new splash image. Any name apart from "splash" will do. I usually name mine "splashscreen".

I have noticed that if you don't do this and simply name the new splashscreen by the name "splash", your app will continue to show the old (default) splash even if you restart your server and clear cache and no matter how many times you reload your app. I don't know why. Maybe it is a bug that Expo team will resolve someday.

Let us know if this works for you. It works for me 100%.

Comment: 2024 same issue here

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing data from the Expo GO app, and run `expo start --clear`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the name of the file from splash.png to another name. It seems like even if you rename another image to 'spash.png', it still renders the Expo default image.
I had the same problem and fixed it by changing the name.

Answer (score 1):

After running `npx expo prebuild`, it should work!

If you want to find out more, here is the link to the youtube.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coJxbYQTFfk

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question right you are still seeing the expo splashscreen when starting the app? Go to `android/app/src/main/res/drawable` and see if the image is there, if it is remove it and test again.

Comment: No, it is not there. I really don't know where is this image and I can't find a way to change it.

Comment: Instead of placing the splash screen image in app.json file. place it in the drawable folder and call it `splashscreen_image` Did you also clean the project with `./gradlew clean` ?  `cd android` and then `./gradlew clean` to back out of android do `cd..`

Comment: I can't find the folders on my project

Comment: When you created the project, did you choose the `managed workflow` or `bare managed workflow`?

Comment: I created the project with the blank option

Comment: Do you even have the android & ios folder in your project?

Answer (score 0):

For an ejected project I had to delete the android folder and rebuild the project, but make sure that there's no edits directly in the android project since those edits will be lost

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an ejected project,

1. open your android folder using Android Studio;
2. Run the android folder using the run button.
   [Where you run the](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlFEH.png)

After it finish executing,
Go to your terminal and execute you

```
npx expo start --dev-client --clear
```